# How to copy same values to another field in attribute table in QGIS using field calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am trying to copy values from `Parsel_ID` to `Parsel_NO` using an equation (look at pictures) in field calculator but it is not working.

What is the problem and how can I success this task?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

- Open attribute table
- Create new column
- Select the new column
- Write the column name which needs to be duplicated
- Click update

[image]

Answer (score 23):

replace

> "Parcel_NO" = "Parcel_ID"

to

> "Parcel_ID"

in expression window

Comment: @RamkumarNarendran Consider to accept this answer, otherwise we might think your issue is unsolved.

Comment: also, make sure that you select all rows that you wish to change first. Otherwise it does not work. QGIS 3