# Getting maximum values of attribute of multiple Shapefiles merged into new shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, merge, batch

I have thousands of points in multiple shapefiles. I want to get the maximum value of an attribute of each shapefile. Then I want to merge all the maximum values to a new layer.

Is there a way to extract max values as a batch process from multiple layers?

EDIT:

This is the sample attribute table. The max values I need are from "DTM50austri" from each Shapefile.

[image: Attribute Table]

This is the query I've tried. "Zusammengeführt" is the merged shapefile.

[image: This is what I've tried]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This can be achieved doing the following steps:**

1. Merge all your shapefiles using `Vector --> Data Management Tools
   --> Merge Vector Layers`
2. Create a new virtual layer `Layer --> Add Layer --> Add/Edit Virtual Layer`
3. Enter the following Query: `Select max("id") as "maxid", "geometry" from "Merged" Group by "path"` *(See explanation below)*
4. Make sure to select `geometry` as Geometry column and `Point` as Type, hit the `Add` button and set virtual layer's CRS to original/merged shapefiles CRS **if needed** *(`Right click layer --> Properties --> Source --> Geometry and Coordinate Reference System`)*
5. You can now save the virtual layer as shapefile or any other supported format *(`Right click layer --> Export --> Save Features As...`)*

**Explantation for the query:**

- `id` is the fieldname of the values you want the maximum's of *(see hint below)*
- `maxid` is the new fieldname for your maximum values in the virtual layer
- `geometry` selects the geometry of your points
- `Merged` is the vector layer of the merged shapefiles
- `path` is a field that will be generated by merging the shapefiles inside `Merged` vector layer and contains paths to your shapefiles as well as their names; so it is unique for each file --> this allows you to select the maximum `id` of **each** shapefile by grouping them by `path`
- `max()` command selects the maximum value of your `id` field

**My Example:**

[image]

In my example I select the maximum id's.

**Additional notes:**

Of course this will only work when the maximum values you want to select all have the same column/attribute name in their original shapefiles! If not, you need to generate a new field in the merged shapefile and [copy the values over to a new column via field calculator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167991/how-to-copy-same-values-to-another-field-in-attribute-table-in-qgis-using-field).

Comment: The problem is I get the **name** of the attribute written in the column "maxid" in the virtual layer and not the numerical values. So the value is always "height" (which is the name of the attribute).  I get the correct amount of max values though. Everything's fine in the merged file. Seems like the query doesn't work for me.Any ideas?

Comment: can you edit your question and provide a screenshot of your attribute table(s) (just a sample) and post the code for the virtual layer you have tried? Is your attribute formatted as a numerical value? or is it a text field with numbers inside?

Comment: I edited the question and added screenshots. The attribute is a numerical value, i just double checked.

Comment: Let me make a wild guess: your screenshot is from the original attribute table and not the merged one, right? Could it be, that the field "DTM50austri" does not exist on the merged one and is called "DTM50austr" instead (10chars limitation for fieldnames of shapefiles)? Otherwise everything looks fine so far...

Comment: On a second look I'm a little confused... Based on your fist comment I think you should write `max("height")` instead of `max("DTM50austri")`

Comment: You guessed right, I made a silly mistake. The last letter got cut off in the merged file. Now it works perfectly fine without the "i". Thanks a lot! (In my first comment I used the word "height" as a simplification.)